# Adding and filling rows for dates in dataframe based on groupby in pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, date, group-by, fill

I have a data frame that could be generated by:

```
import pandas as pd
data = [['tom', 10, '20190202',5], ['nick', 15,'20190202',7], ['juli', 16,'20190203',8],
        ['tom', 17,'20190204',6], ['tom', 10,'20190204',9], ['nick', 15,'20190207',3]] 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Employee', 'ID','Date','Value'])
```

The dataframe looks like this:

[image]

I need output like this:

[image]

The new dataframe needs to be generated based on following assumption:
For all the "Employee" and "ID" the max date is found and the data from previous last entry for the "Employee" and "ID" is duplicated in rows until maximum date is reached.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

@jezrel answer works perfectly well. but just for audience to have multiple options adding mine too as this also

```
df['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

def expand_dates(ser):
    return pd.DataFrame({'Date': pd.date_range(ser['Date'].min(), df['Date'].max(), freq='D')})

newdf = df.groupby(['Employee', 'ID']).apply(expand_dates).reset_index()\
          .merge(df, how='left')[['Employee', 'ID','Date','Value']].ffill()
```

Answer (score 3):

First create `DatetimeIndex` by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and in [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) use custom lambda function with [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) per minimal datetime per group with maximal datetime of column `Date` with forward filling missing values:

```
#convert to datetimes if necessary
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

df = (df.set_index('Date')
        .groupby(['Employee', 'ID'], sort=False)['Value']
        .apply(lambda x: x.reindex(pd.date_range(x.index.min(), 
                                                 df['Date'].max(), 
                                                 name='Date'), method='ffill'))
        .reset_index())
print (df)
   Employee  ID       Date  Value
0       tom  10 2019-02-02      5
1       tom  10 2019-02-03      5
2       tom  10 2019-02-04      9
3       tom  10 2019-02-05      9
4       tom  10 2019-02-06      9
5       tom  10 2019-02-07      9
6      nick  15 2019-02-02      7
7      nick  15 2019-02-03      7
8      nick  15 2019-02-04      7
9      nick  15 2019-02-05      7
10     nick  15 2019-02-06      7
11     nick  15 2019-02-07      3
12     juli  14 2019-02-03      8
13     juli  14 2019-02-04      8
14     juli  14 2019-02-05      8
15     juli  14 2019-02-06      8
16     juli  14 2019-02-07      8
17      tom  14 2019-02-04      6
18      tom  14 2019-02-05      6
19      tom  14 2019-02-06      6
20      tom  14 2019-02-07      6
```